# elementary set theory (cartesian product and symmetric difference proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've figured out the following statement is true but I was wondering how you actually go about proving something like this?

$A \times (B \triangle C) = (A \times B) \triangle (A \times C)$

Comment: One possible approach: to show that two sets are equal, prove two inclusions, i.e. that $\text{LHS}\subseteq\text{RHS}$ and that $\text{RHS}\subseteq\text{LHS}$. And each inclusion proof can be done element-wise: for example, pick an arbitrary $x\in\text{LHS}$ and by using the definitions of these set operations show that $x\in\text{RHS}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my answer in [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154991/set-theory-proof-cartesian-products-symmetric-differences?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> **Def**. let be $E,F$ sets: $$E \bigtriangleup F := (E \setminus F) \cup (F\setminus E)$$
>
> **The**. let be $A,B,C$ sets: $$A \times (B \bigtriangleup C)=(A \times  B) \bigtriangleup (A \times C)$$
>   **Proof**: $$ \begin{align} A \times (B \bigtriangleup C) &= A \times ((B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)) \\&= (A \times (B\setminus C)) \cup (A \times (C \setminus B)) \\&=((A \times B)\setminus (A \times C)) \cup ((A \times C) \setminus (A \times B)) \\&=(A\times B)\bigtriangleup (A \times C)\end{align}$$
>   I used ["Cartesian Product Distributes over Union"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Distributes_over_Union) and ["Cartesian Product Distributes over Set Difference"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Distributes_over_Set_Difference)

Answer (score 1):

A nice approach is by comparing the characteristic functions. Note that :

$(x,y)\in A\times B\Leftrightarrow \left(x\in A\,\mathrm{and}\,y\in B\right)$

so that $1_{A\times B}=1_A\times 1_B$

Also $1_{A\Delta B}=1_A\oplus A_B$ where $\oplus$ denotes mod 2 addition.

Now the required proof is straightforward.