# set theory proof (cartesian products/symmetric differences)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove this theorem - Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets. Then, $A \times (B \Delta C) = (A \times B) \Delta (A \times C)$.

I was wondering if this was the right way to start the proof?

Let $m$ be an arbitrary element of $A \times (B \Delta C)$. Then, $m=(x,y)$ s.t. $x \in A$ and $y \in (B \Delta C)$ by the definition of cartesian products. Then, $(m \in A) \land (y \in B) \land (y \not\in C)$ by the definition of set difference. So, $((x,y) \in A \times B) \land ((x,y) \not\in A \times C)$ by the definition of cartesian product. Thus, $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \Delta (A \times C)$.

So basically the LHS = RHS because (x,y) is an element of both sides?

Comment: First thing: $(x,y)$ is an *element*, not a subset, of these sets.

Comment: Right, fixed that. Thanks

Comment: Second: you should take a closer look at the definition of a *symmetric* difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Def**. let be $E,F$ sets: $$E \bigtriangleup F := (E \setminus F) \cup (F\setminus E)$$
>
> **The**. let be $A,B,C$ sets: $$A \times (B \bigtriangleup C)=(A \times  B) \bigtriangleup (A \times C)$$
>   **Proof**: $$ \begin{align} A \times (B \bigtriangleup C) &= A \times ((B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)) \\&= (A \times (B\setminus C)) \cup (A \times (C \setminus B)) \\&=((A \times B)\setminus (A \times C)) \cup ((A \times C) \setminus (A \times B)) \\&=(A\times B)\bigtriangleup (A \times C)\end{align}$$
>   I used ["Cartesian Product Distributes over Union"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Distributes_over_Union) and ["Cartesian Product Distributes over Set Difference"](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_Distributes_over_Set_Difference)